# How to change Developer name under information section in testflight

Tags: ios, testflight

I want to change Developer name Under information section and also Under Version Number.Please suggest me from where i can change it. thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Contact Apple.

> **Updating Your Information**
>
> To update the Apple ID and/or email address associated with your
>   account, visit My Apple ID, click "Manage your account", and sign in
>   with your current Apple ID and password.
>
> To update your address, contact information, or organization name,
>   please contact us. Note that certain updates, such as changes to your
>   name or address, must be verified and approved, as this information is
>   associated with contracts between you and Apple. You will be asked to
>   provide documentation that reflects the changes you request.

Reference: [Apple Account Management Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/account/)

Comment: Visit this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html